# Cannot sign in to Microsoft Teams on Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, microsoft-teams

I have tried to sign in to Microsoft Teams with the same Microsoft account

1. in a web browser,
2. in the Microsoft Teams application on a Windows 10 machine,
3. in the Microsoft Teams application on an Ubuntu 20.04 machine.

(1) and (2) works OK. (3) does not.

If I try to sign in on Ubuntu, I get the message

> Someone has already set up Teams for your organization. Ask your admin
> to get you started with Teams, or set up another org in Teams using a
> different email address.

I have installed the package 1.5.00.10453 amd64.
I am using MS Teams for free.
I am not a member of any organization, I am using my personal Microsoft account.

Is there a way to troubleshoot this?
...or is this just some limitation of the Ubuntu application that it cannot be used under the circumstances mentioned above?

Comment: Did you install the Teams application from the .deb file or from snaps?  MIcrosoft has said to not use the .deb and use snaps lately, due to 22.04 issues and NEWER featuresets available than in the .deb (which is outdated / not updated)

Comment: @ThomasWard I installed the application from the deb file.

Comment: @ThomasWard I have just tried to install the snap teams-for-linux and it works fine.

Comment: @ThomasWard However, teams-for-linux is some unofficial snap that just wraps the web version. When I tried the offical snap teams, it has the same issue as the version from deb file.

Comment: is this an Office 365 Microsoft account or a personal Teams account?  The Teams application for Linux is like the "Teams (for work or school)" app in Windows that has to be installed separately, it does NOT function for personal Outlook/Microsoft accounts.  This i believe is a known limitation for the Teams clients that MIcrosoft is aware of.  And for odd reasons they have **completely separate Teams clients** for Personal and for MS365 work/organization accounts.

Comment: @ThomasWard It is a personal account. Thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @ThomasWard in comments, the Linux application works only with an Office 365 Microsoft account.

Besides that, an unofficial snap teams-for-linux can be used.
It is a standalone application that just wraps the web version of Teams.